# plot with automatic offset correction

Tags: pgfplots, math-operators

i have a lot of measurement data file and want to compare them in a plot. The data file looks like this

```
0,00000     -0,39875    -1,96508 
0,05000     -0,38791    -1,95986 
0,10000     -0,38026    -1,95792 
0,15000     -0,37083    -1,95451 
0,20000     -0,35972    -1,94957
```

Yes there is no header, separatur is tab and we have , and not . for the decimal place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [name=plot, legend pos=outer north east]
    \addplot[red] 
        table [
                /pgf/number format/read comma as period,
                col sep=tab,
                x index=1,
                y index=2,
#                y expr=(\thisrowno{2})*-1 % <- Error
            ]
            {./Data/07062022-1434.txt};
    \addlegendentry{100mHz}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Not the data has an offset. First step i can calculate it manualy and correct the data before i latex plot them. I want to this with the one comment line but it don't work. I always get this error message:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `2Y1.0e0]1Y9.5986e4]'. The unreadable part was near '2Y1.0e0]1Y9.5986e4]'. (in '(-1,95986)*-1').
```

Why? Does table not correct convert the data?

The next step is, that latex automaticaly calculates the offset.
This is the calulation:

```
Offset = (abs(max)-abs(min))/2
```

of colum 2. Is this possible.

I cannot manipulate the files manual because i have a lot of files and i must compare differant files (case) togehter in a graphical diagram.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome. //  Looks like a strange data format to me, in the error message.

Comment: Seems sth is wrong with `/pgf/number format/read comma as period` and `y expr`. If I replace commas with periods in your data file, then it all work.

Comment: Or, if the data file starts with a column name line, for example `col0  col1 col2`, then `y expr=(-thisrow("col2"))*-1` works.

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/440

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
red,
mark=*,
y filter/.expression={-y},
] table[
header=false,
col sep=tab,
x index=1,
y index=2,
/pgf/number format/read comma as period,
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with red plot]